# Subclass calling Base Class constructor then using instance method of Base Class in Subclass Arduino C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, arduino

I have a Base Class `FCBRelay` and within that class it deals with setting up of the relay to a pin and holding general methods such as `on` or `onForTime`.

When I attempt to call `onForTime` within the Subclass it won't compile giving the error:

```
cannot call member function 'void FCBRelay::onForTime(int)' without object
```

Now I understand what the error is saying as the `onForTime` method is not **static** but my Subclass constructor calls the Base Class constructor too. Or so says my understanding.

The idea of this is to be more descriptive in my `main` function. Rather than calling `waterPump.onForTime(2);` I could call `waterPump.squirt(2);`

My Classes are as below

---

**FCBRelay.h**

```
#ifndef FCBRelay_H
#define FCBRelay_H

#include <Arduino.h>

class FCBRelay {
  public:
    FCBRelay(int pinNo);

    int delayTime;

    void tick();
    void onForTime(int timeInSeconds);

  private:
    int _pinNumber;
    int _lastTickMillis;

    void on();
    void off();
};

#endif
```

**FCBRelay.cpp**

```
#include "FCBRelay.h"

FCBRelay::FCBRelay(int pinNo) {
  _pinNumber = pinNo;
  pinMode(_pinNumber, OUTPUT);
}

void FCBRelay::onForTime(int timeInSeconds) {
  delayTime = timeInSeconds * 1000;
  on();
}

void FCBRelay::tick() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if((currentMillis - _lastTickMillis) >= delayTime) {
      _lastTickMillis = currentMillis;
      off();
  }
}

void FCBRelay::on() {
  digitalWrite(_pinNumber, HIGH);
}

void FCBRelay::off() {
  digitalWrite(_pinNumber, LOW);
}
```

---

**FCBWaterPump.h**

```
#ifndef FCBWaterPump_H
#define FCBWaterPump_H

#include "FCBRelay.h"

class FCBWaterPump : public FCBRelay {
  public:
    FCBWaterPump(int pinNo);

    void squirt(int timeInSeconds);
};

#endif
```

**FCBWaterPump.cpp**

```
#include "FCBWaterPump.h"

FCBWaterPump::FCBWaterPump(int pinNo) : FCBRelay(pinNo) {

}

void squirt(int timeInSeconds) {
  FCBRelay::onForTime(timeInSeconds);
}
```

---

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You accidentally wrote a stand-alone function.  That's why there's no object.

Change this:

```
void squirt(int timeInSeconds) {
  FCBRelay::onForTime(timeInSeconds);
}
```

to this:

```
void FCBWaterPump::squirt(int timeInSeconds) {
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  FCBRelay::onForTime(timeInSeconds);
}
```

Comment: I have just this second found that too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should select this answer, @StePrescott